# How to get id of a pinned list View in Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I need to redirect User to the pinned list view of a certain object on the click of a custom button in the lightning component.
I can't see any field on list view object which specified pinned list view.

Answer (score 2):

This information is stored in the browser cache so there'd be no way for you to get this information through apex/Salesforce like you're attempting.

This [help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=basics_pinned_list_views_lex.htm&type=5) and the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_lex_pinned_lists.htm) mention how it's per users and how it doesn't sync across browsers

[image]

There's an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CYkcQAG) about how you lose this pinned list view if you clear your specific browser cache as well.